# Integral of $\int{x+3\over (3-2x)^{2\over 3}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

I am finding the ingetral of:

$$\int{x+3\over (3-2x)^{2\over 3}}$$

So,

$u=3-2x$, $_{}$ $du=-2 dx$,$_{}$ and  $x={1\over 2}(u-3)$

$$\int{{1\over 2}(u-3)+3 \over u^{3\over 2}}({-{1\over 2}})du
\\ = {-{1\over 2}}\int {{u\over 2} +{3\over 2}\over u^{2\over 3}} du
\\ = {-{1\over 2}}\int{u+3 \over 2u^{2\over 3}} du
\\ ={-{1\over 2}}\int {1\over 2} \cdot{u+3 \over u^{2\over 3}} du
\\ = {-{1\over 4}}\int{u+3 \over u^{2\over 3}} du
\\ = {-{1\over 4}}\int{u \over u^{2 \over 3}}du {-{1\over 4}}\int{-3 \over u^{2\over 3}}du
\\ = {-{1\over 4}}\int u^{-{1\over 3}} du {-{3\over 4}}\int u^{-{2\over 3}} du
\\ = {-{1\over 4}}({u^{2\over 3} \over {2 \over 3}}) + {3\over 4} ({u^{1\over 3} \over {1 \over 3}})
\\ = {-{3\over 8}}(u^{2\over 3})-{9\over 4}(u^{1\over 3})
\\ = {-{3\over 8}}(3-2x)^{2\over 3} + {9\over 4}(3-2x)^{1\over 3}$$

It turns out that this is wrong. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Doesn't $x=0.5(3-u)$?

Comment: One observation: if $u=3-2x$, $x=\frac{1}{2}(3-u)$. That is not what you have.

Comment: Very simple mistake I made there... Now I have to do everything again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int{x+3\over (3-2x)^{2\over 3}}dx$$
$$u=(3-2x)\Rightarrow du=-2dx$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}(3-u)+3}{u^\frac{2}{3}}du$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\int-\frac{u-9}{2u^\frac{2}{3}}du$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\frac{u}{u^\frac{2}{3}}du-\int\frac{9}{u^\frac{2}{3}}du\right)\right)$$
$$\int\frac{u}{u^\frac{2}{3}}du\Rightarrow \frac{3u^\frac{4}{3}}{4},\int\frac{9}{u^\frac{2}{3}}du\Rightarrow 27\sqrt[3]{u}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3(3-2x)^\frac{4}{3}}{4}-27\sqrt[3]{3-2x}\right)\right)+C$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{3}{4}(3-2x)^\frac{4}{3}-27\sqrt[3]{3-2x}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$3-2x=u^3$$
$$\int{x+3\over (3-2x)^{2\over 3}}dx=-\frac{3}{4}\int(9-u^3)du=\frac{3}{16}u^4-\frac{27}{4}u+c$$